# How to create a 1 Year Range Style Chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm wondering if the below is possible - similar to a box plot in many ways, but displayed differently:

- A horizontal plot where by the widest arms are the range of the data over the past 52 weeks (say from 0 to 90)
- A box along that line showing the range of values in the last 4 weeks
- A dot showing current value

I have attempted to convert a boxplot into such a figure but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding the question. Is the shown image what you want or what you are able to achieve with a box plot? I would appreciate clarification or e.g. add an image sketching what the intended plot should look like.

Comment: What you want is to plot a line, a rectange and a dot. All is sure possible with matplotlib. Mind that questions on SO should have a clear problem description. As of now what you describe is a task, not a problem. What is the problem (note that "no avail" is not sufficient)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - yes that is right. I guess my problem is I am completely unable to achieve this, hence why it this question looks like a task rather than a question. I don't need to do this as a task per sé, I was just interested if this is possible, and if so, how.

Comment: It seems like it is a matter of masking your data into the previous 52 weeks and the previous 4 weeks and taking the min and max of the masked data and feeding it into your line and rect functions. How is your data stored? You should be able to perform the masking easily if your data is in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: It is a task in the sense that you haven't shown any attempt to solve it or at least haven't stated in how far you are unable to do it. The reason we don't want to have such questions is that SO is not meant to be a code-writing-service. I'm sure you are able to draw a line, a rectangle and a dot. So update your question with what you have tried and clearly state at what point it fails (often the problem thereby simplifies drastically and you will even find a solution for each problematic step by yourself).